# How many simultaneous connections can be established to a Bluetooth device at a time?

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, server, serversocket, rfcomm

"The Bluetooth protocol RFCOMM is a simple set of transport protocols, made on top of the L2CAP protocol, providing emulated RS-232 serial ports (up to sixty simultaneous connections to a Bluetooth device at a time)."

I got it from google. But how can a server listen for multiple UUIDs and accept multiple connections at a time. Is there any documnetation for that.

Please suggest. Thanks ina advance.